# I am trying to make the buttons side by side in a vertical flex div

Tags: html, css

I have a particular issue where my container's css gives the textarea and buttons a vertical flex direction. I only want the buttons to be aligned vertically with the textarea, which that vertical flex direction does, but I want my two buttons to be side by side.

As you can see in the following HTML, I tried to apply a row flex direction to just the .buttons class, but that hasn't fixed my issue. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
.body {
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/dQtH57ix3NWDKOQeQM/giphy.gif);
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #00000d;
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: .8;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.proxies {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: #00000d;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  resize: none;
}

.buttons {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.close {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
}

.add {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5276b58f35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<right class="body">
  <div class="fill">
    <textarea class="proxies" name="proxies" id="proxies" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="ip:port:name:pass"></textarea>
    <div class="buttons"></div>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
    <button class="add">Add Proxies</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</right>
```

Comment: There is no `<right>` element

Comment: I'm aware. It's just an identifier instead of putting div, which makes no difference.

Comment: it makes a difference because random element are inline by default so it's not like puttin a div but like putting a span

Comment: Ah, I gotcha ty temani afif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the buttons in their own div and you should have it

```
 <right class="body">
      <div class="fill">
        <textarea class="proxies" name="proxies" id="proxies" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="ip:port:name:pass"></textarea>
        <div class="buttons"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="close">Close</button>
          <button class="add">Add Proxies</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </right>
```

css for spacing

```
.close {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: yellow;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I had accidentally opened the button div and closed it before the buttons haha

Comment: I realised i just named the class the same as what you already have, but you get the idea

Comment: aha no problem.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, is there a way to add a bit of spacing between the two buttons?

Comment: yeah just add a margin right to the .close button, will edit the post above

Comment: no problem, do you mind ticking the comment as answered? take care